# Can text chat be disabled on Hyper Scape?

Tags: ubisoft-connect, hyper-scape

I'd like to know if it's possible to disable text chat on Hyper Scape.  I know voice chat has a volume which I assume means you can mute it.  I'm ok with quick chat like rocket league, but I'd like to disable typed messages.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but I do think there is an alternative solution, you can mute everyone's text chat.

Comment: would I have to do that for each individual player, or is their a mute all button?  I have seen people complain that text chat is disabled in a bug or something, but they acted like it was a feature to disable it and the bug was using that feature, but I haven't gotten confirmation.

Comment: That I'm not sure about, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately, Hyper Scape's servers shut down on April 28, 2022.